# Gitlab CI pipeline syntax query

Tags: gitlab-ci

We have a Gitlab CI pipeline (.gitlab-ci.yml file)

In that file there are 3 stages

stages:

- build
- validate
- deploy:stage

Firstly, there are 2 jobs

validate:rules:

stage: validate

validate:charts:

stage: validate

Secondly, there is a job that does not have a stage announced inside,

.deploy: &deploy

Later, there is another job:

job-abc:

<<: *deploy

stage: deploy:stage

Q1: can we call same stage in 2 jobs as it has been done in case of validate:rules and validate:charts.

Q2: what is the generic purpose of using double colon in job names such as validate:rules.

Q3: It will be helpful if someone can explain ".deploy: &deploy" and "<<: *deploy" above.

Comment: See the GitLab docs on [YAML Optimization](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html) for your third question.

Comment: @doelleri I had a look at the above link and found answer for the third question